# multiple shaking instances using conditionals in android

Tags: android, conditional-statements, shake

I'm having trouble choosing a conditional so that every time the user shakes the device a different text string shows up on screen. Which conditional should I use for this (switch/case,do/while,etc)? Here is my code:

```
    mSensorListener.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeEventListener.OnShakeListener() {

      public void onShake() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Shake!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the messages in a `String` array and use `Random` to select one of the messages.

In the top of your activity define a global `Random` object:

```
Random random = new Random();
```

Also globally specify a `String` array to hold the messages:

```
String[] messages = new String[] {"Hello", "World", "Shake", "Potato", "Banana for scale", "To the moon"};
```

Then randomly choose and display one in your `ShakeEventListener`:

```
mSensorListener.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeEventListener.OnShakeListener() {

    public void onShake() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, messages[random.nextInt(messages.length)], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 });
```

Comment: works great. It's a little sensitive on the shakiness though.